# error: checksum failure file: sources/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz

Tags: software-installation, compiling, downloads, source-packages

I am try to download RTEMS source builder and build a tool chain following the instruction in [this page](https://docs.rtems.org/branches/master/user/start/index.html). The problem that I have seems to be a package download automatically through *sourceforge.net*: it seems that the chacksum is different. Here the hot part of the log file:

```
source setup: expat-2.1.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-1: source expat -q -n expat-2.1.0
making dir: /home/leonardo/development/rtems/rsb/rtems/sources
download: (full) http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz -> sources/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
download: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz -> sources/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
 redirect: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/#!/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
 redirect: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/#!/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
checksums: expat-2.1.0.tar.gz:  7a07d3f7cca5c0b38ca811984ef8da536da32932d68c1a6cce33ec2462b930bf => 823705472f816df21c8f6aa026dd162b280806838bb55b3432b0fb1fcca7eb86
warning: checksum error: expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
error: checksum failure file: sources/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
```

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Today is faulty day for sourceforge.net. I can't get font files for `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` four hours ago. You can retry your download.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the tar file directly from the link and move the downloaded file to /rtems-source-builder/rtems/sources